# Publishing with Elsevier - Does the manuscript have the author info?

Tags: paper-submission

I am uploading a paper for an Elsevier journal. The system indicates that a Manuscript should be uploaded. I don't have previous experience with this system. My question is: should the Manuscript exclude all the information about the author? Or should the manuscript be the whole paper in its final form?

Comment: This information is usually provided by the journal, not the publisher. Could you provide us the journal name? Hint: you are looking whether the journal review process is single-blind or double-blind (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review#Different_styles_of_review)

Comment: Did you check the instructions for authors? A manuscript should always be complete with author names, affiliation and addresses unless specified otherwise. Some journals anonymize papers but that should be clear at the time of  submission

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the comments: each journal sets his editorial policy, which is clearly stated on the journal's website and instructions to authors. For example, *Journal of Accounting and Economics*:

> This journal employs a single blind review, where the referee remains anonymous throughout the process (http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-accounting-and-economics/policies/peer-review-policy-for-the-journal-of-accounting-and/)

and *Computers and Education*:

> This journal employs double blind reviewing, where both the referee and author remain anonymous throughout the process (http://www.journals.elsevier.com/computers-and-education/policies/peer-review-policy-on-computers-education/)

If you want to submit to a journal with double-blind review, do not include authors' name (or any other incriminating information, for example in acknowledgments). If single blind, then include the author names in the manuscript.